# Why do I get a 'http:// wrapper is disabled' error even though allow_url_fopen is enabled in my php.ini file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel

I am facing a  file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 error but in my php.ini file allow_url_fopen=1.

My php.ini at server

```
; cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
; Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
; To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
; For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)

allow_url_fopen = 1
allow_url_include = On
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 300000
max_input_time = 600000
max_input_vars = 100000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 150M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440000
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
upload_max_filesize = 100M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

My Controller

```
    public function send_sms_using_api($api, $contact_no, $sms_content){
    
       if (empty($api)) { return 'API not exist in DB'; }

       $api = str_replace("{CONTACT}",$contact_no,$api);
        
       $api = str_replace("{MESSAGE}",$sms_content,$api);

       
        $output = file_get_contents($api);

        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` to get a dump of configuration values. It should tell you which INI files are in play